# Swift: How to create a custom overridden UITableView with a generic type for its delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I would like to create a UITableView, and with this a new delegate. Basically:

```
class GenericTableView: UITableView {    
    weak var customDelegate: GenericTableViewDelegate?
}

protocol GenericTableViewDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    func genericTableView(_ genericTableView: GenericTableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
}
```

But now I would like to add a generic type associated to this delegate :

```
protocol GenericTableViewDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    associatedtype T   
    func cellFor(object: T) -> UITableViewCell    
}
```

And this error appears where I define the customDelegate:

> Protocol 'GenericTableViewDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

I understand this problem, but I have no idea of what to do instead.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states:

> Protocol 'GenericTableViewDelegate' **can only be used as a generic constraint** because it has Self or associated type requirements.

So, let's do that instead:

```swift
class GenericTableView<Delegate: GenericTableViewDelegate>: UITableView {
    weak var customDelegate: Delegate?
}
```